# I did a hard reset during memory dump following a BSOD on Windows 10 and my computer does not boot

Tags: laptop, memory, bsod, reboot, reset

I was on battery, browsing the web and my laptop froze.

I then pressed the ON/OFF button to do a hard reset.
During this, a BSOD appeared, which made me "kill" my computer during memory dump (at 0%).

I tried to reboot but my laptop is stuck on the OEM logo and then goes to BIOS.

In the BIOS, I resetted to default values, not a change.

I removed the battery, pressed on ON/OFF several times, let it rest for 10 minutes, put the battery back on again and tried to restart. Still stuck at boot/BIOS.

Do I have to remove the whole cover of my laptop (ASUS N551JK) to remove the CMOS battery or is there another solution?

Here are my specs, just in case:

- ASUS N551JK
- Intel Core i7-4710HQ
- 16GB RAM
- 128 GB SSD + 1TB HDD (boot on SSD)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M

Comment: You may have a hardware problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What would be the problem? I understand that a BSOD is bad, but I have some in the past when I am on battery (not when on A/C). So it is not specific to this BSOD episode.

Comment: It's even worse when BSODs are common - you shouldn't have any. Many times the problem is caused by a power fluctuation that cooked some component, which is why a UPS is often counseled when connected to the mains. I really can't be more specific, since there are just too many possibilities. Maybe a repairman can help.

Comment: I see, but here I was on battery, and the battery is not faulty. Well, common is a big word, I have it when I use MATLAB on battery, it's the first time that the BSOD happened outside of this configuration.

It does display something, so I wouldn't say that the computer is completely fried. The RAM neither, I would not be able to go anywhere if RAM was faulty. The motherboard seems to work seems the computer starts. Remain the hard drives, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment more without hands-on.

Comment: I understand. If you could, how would  you go about troubleshooting? What should I look at first? Thanks a lot for your help.